# What are the ICAO equipment codes for those Garmin units?

Tags: flight-planning, avionics, icao

What are the ICAO [equipment codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipment_codes) for those Garmin units?

- Garmin G500 / 750 / 650 WAAS navigators?

Answer (score 4):

For the GTN 6XX/7XX and GNS 4XXW/5XXW they are:

```
A1/B2/C2/D2/L1/O2/S1/S2
```

---

Source: [garmin.com](https://fly.garmin.com/fly-garmin/support/icao-flight-plans) — scroll down to the link that reads: <s>"Garmin Flight Plan Information Excel file".</s>

The Excel file was taken down; the page now refers to a Garmin app. For informational purposes only, that Excel file is available [via Web Archive via sportys.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20210520194229/https://dl.videos.sportys.com/assets/IPN/Garmin_ICAO_Flight_Plan.xlsx) (thanks @user2070305).

Comment: I did not find a reference to the Excel file at the garmin.com link above, but did find a copy cached at [Sporty's](https://dl.videos.sportys.com/assets/IPN/Garmin_ICAO_Flight_Plan.xlsx) reference in an article at [iPad Pilot News](https://ipadpilotnews.com/2020/08/how-to-set-up-an-icao-compliant-aircraft-profiles-when-filing-flight-plans/) that may be useful.