# What are the ICAO RNAV equipment codes for the non-WAAS G1000 and GNS 430W?

Tags: flight-planning, icao-sarps, g1000, gns430

When filing an ICAO IFR flight plan, where in "the manual" (which manual?) for a G1000 and a GNS430 do I find the RNAV capability information for an ICAO flight plan? What am I looking for?

Comment: Related: [What are the ICAO equipment codes for those Garmin units? [closed\]](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/51824/14897)

Answer (score 3):

[Garmin's ICAO Equipment Guide](https://support.foreflight.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049193173-ICAO-Equipment-Guide) is very helpful indicating

> Non-WAAS
> G1000                - R and PBN B2, C2, D2
>
> WAAS
> GNS 430W             - R, B, and PBN B2, C2, D2

This corresponds with [AIM TBL 5-1-6](https://www.faa.gov/Air_traffic/Publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap5_section_1.html) which can include "up to a maximum of 8 entries"
[image: AIM TBL 5-1-6]

**But where do I find this in the manual?**

Garmin also has this [ICAO PBN/RNAV-RNP Codes](https://support.garmin.com/en-US/aviation/faq/hDbN1ryrqe4GkBour6SzC8/?keywordSearch=ICAO%20PBN%2FRNAV-RNP%20Codes) site which explicitly states:

> ***Note:** Please reference your navigator and transponder's **Aircraft Flight Manual Supplement (AFMS)** for details on which codes apply to your avionics.  For integrated flight decks please consult your OEM.*

After an Internet search, I found an ***example*** [Diamond DA40 Airplane Flight Manual Supplement G1000 Integrated Avionics System](https://www.flights-inc.com/manuals/G1000_Diamond_AirplaneFlightManualSupplement.pdf)

I believe the answer is in the **SECTION I GENERAL** on page 9. This still depends on knowing what exact equipment you have. For example:

> Oceanic/Remote per FAA Notice 8110.60 -- Two FMSs are
> required to be installed...

Please leave a comment this was helpful to anyone else, or if anything is inaccurate or missing.

Comment: Self answering is very encouraged, no need making the answer wiki. Feel free to resubmit as a normal answer.

Comment: Is there a way to make it not a wiki, or do I need to delete and repost? I found I cannot delete and repost (at least not in a near time frame).

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a limitation on delete/repost for you, but at least next time just make it a normal answer ;)